# MEDIA_URL and redirect not working

Tags: python, django, redirect, media-url

I'm beginner in django, so started my test project.

There is a home.html which gives options to register or login/logoff. Also I created a separate app `registration` for handling these requests.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media').replace('\\','/')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {"template": "home.html",}, name="home"),
url(r'^register/', direct_to_template, {"template": "register.html",}, name="register"),
url(r'^accounts', include('registration.urls')),
```

**base.html**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css" />
</head><body>

<div style="text-align: right;">
    <form action="/accounts/login" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><span>Username:</span><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p><span>Password:</span><input type="password" name="password"/></p>
    <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /> </p>
    </form>
    <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
</div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
<p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>
    This is a test site. If you do not have an account, <a href="/register">Register</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Register </h1> <br />
<form action="/accounts" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><span>Username:</span><input type="text" name="username" /></p><br />
    <p><span>Email:</span><input type="text" name="email" /></p><br />
    <p><span>Password:</span><input type="password" name="password"/></p><br />
    <p><span>Re-password:</span><input type="password" name="repassword"/></p><br />
    <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Register" /> </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py - registration**

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^$', registerfun),
url(r'/login$', loginfun),
url(r'/logout$', logoutfun),
```

**views.py - registration**

```
def registerfun(request):
    #validate and obtain request parameters
    if not errors:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.save()
    return render_to_response('home.html',{'errors':errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def loginfun(request):
    #obtaion request parameters
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return render_to_response('home.html')
        else:
        errors.append('Account disabled')
        return render_to_response('home.html',{'errors':errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        errors.append('Invalid username/password')
        return render_to_response('home.html',{'errors':errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm facing 2 problems

- css is not loading. It's under `media/style.css`.
- when logging in and logging out, the url changes from /accounts/login to /accounts/logout. How shall I avoid it and make it stay at root? Also when I try logging in when I'm on http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout page it's giving me `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error

Answer (score 0):

how do you include your css? It should be:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}path/to/css.css
```

In your case:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css
```

Logout should be

```
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home')) #whatever url you'd like
```

Comment: I have set MEDIA_URL as above but it doesn't load. HttpResponseRedirect does the trick. thanks.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css" />

Comment: you should check what to do with MEDIA_URL... I always set it this way: MEDIA_URL = '../media' to save images outsite the root

Answer (score 0):

If you use django testserver, you should use serve static view, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#limiting-use-to-debug-true

CSRF problem

1. Put {% csrf_token %} tag **inside** each POST form каждой POST form
2. Put '**django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware**' into MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES at settings.py